# How to capture multiple images from camera using image_picker package in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, camera, imagepicker

**I'm trying to capture multiple images from the camera using the image_picker package in Flutter. I've implemented the following code to achieve this:**

```
final picker = ImagePicker();
List<File> selectedImages = [];

Future<void> pickImagesFromCamera() async {
  try {
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        selectedImages.add(File(pickedFile.path));
      });

      if (selectedImages.length < 3) {
        pickImagesFromCamera();
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  }
}
```

While the code works and captures images, it only captures one image from the camera. The expected behavior is to capture multiple images sequentially until a certain limit is reached (in this case, 3 images). However, despite implementing the recursive call in the pickImagesFromCamera function, the capture process stops after the first image.

Comment: check this package https://pub.dev/packages/multiple_image_camera